# Writing asp.net Textbox data into Excel form

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

I have a doubt related to asp.net c#. I am developing a web project, in which, there is a web form, that has a number of textbox entries and a submit button.

After entering the data in the textboxes and clicking submit button, all the data should be read from the Textboxes and inserted in to an Excel document designed in the form of a "form". The Excel document has texboxes, which need to be populated from the asp.net webform. How is this possible ?

I have a concept in mind :- I will upload a copy of the Excel sheet into the website. When a user filles the form and click on submit, an instance of the Excel document is called, and data is inserted. After that, the Excel sheet instance is renamed as "username" and saved somewhere. Is it possible to create instances of Excel sheetslike this ?

Also, I have a second question. Each of the user is required to fill this webform. Suppose that a user fills the form on 1st of that month, the web form will be disabled or hidden to that user for the remaining days, ad will only become active on the 1st of next month. How is this possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Quick tip is to use database in the background to store the data and use second application to pool that data from database into excel on demand.

What your need is possible but it will require some work and experimenting…

My strong recommendation is not to use excel for storage but some database. You’ll end up with a solution that’s difficult to maintain, to extend and such…

Comment: Yeah, I'm using  a database in the backend. I just need to insert the data into database, and then also write it into a excel form.